# Two random variables $X,Y$ such that $X+Y$ has the same distribution as $X$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two almost surely finite real-valued random variables which are not necessarily independent. Assume that $X$ is non-negative and $Y$ has a finite, positive mean. Is it possible that $X+Y$ has the same distribution as $X$?

Note that this is trivial if $\mathbb E(X) < \infty$, so we can restrict attention to the case when $\mathbb E(X) = \infty$. It is also easy to prove using characteristic functions if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, but I am interested in the case when they are not independent.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible even if $X$ can be negative.

Let $\mathrm{Tr}_d(x) = \max(-d, \min(x, d))$, i.e. the truncation of a real number $x$ to $[-d,d]$.

**Proposition:** $\lim_{d→∞} (E(\mathrm{Tr}_d(X+Y)) - E(\mathrm{Tr}_d(X))) = E(Y)$  (assuming $E(Y)$ exists).

*Notes:*
* Thus, $X+Y$ has different distribution from $X$ if $E(Y)≠0$.
* Truncation to $[-d_1,d_2]$ also works as long as $\min(d_1,d_2)→∞$.
* The proposition also holds if $E(Y)=∞$ or $E(Y)=-∞$.

**Proof:**  Since $E(|Y|)$ is finite, the relevant contribution from points with $|Y|>c$ approaches 0 (independent of $d$) as $c→∞$, so we can assume $|Y|≤c$ for a constant $c$.  Then, for every point,
$|\mathrm{Tr}_d(X+Y)-\mathrm{Tr}_d(X)|≤c$ and
$\mathrm{Tr}_d(X+Y)-\mathrm{Tr}_d(X) ≠ Y ⇒ \max(|X|, |X+Y|)>d-c$, which happens with probability $→0$ as $d→∞$.

Comment: More simply, if you let $Z_d=\text{Tr}_d(X+Y)-\text{Tr}_d(X)$, then it is trivially true that $Z_d\to Y$ a.s. when $d\to\infty$, and pretty easy to see $|Z_d|\le |Y|\in L_1$. Therefore, DCT implies $\lim_{d\to \infty}E[Z_d]=E[Y]$, which is exactly your proposition.